# Stability of Lithium hydride over Sodium hydride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, alkali-metals

Why is LiH more stable to heat compared to NaH?

The lithium cation is harder than the sodium cation. The hydride ion is soft. Hence, I would assume that LiH would be more stable compared to NaH, owing to the better interaction that results between a less hard and soft species (NaH) over the interaction between two species of more extreme hardness (LiH).

Comment: Softness and hardness are not good indicators of thermal stability.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71598/confusion-in-comparing-melting-point

Comment: What could be some attributes that hardness and softness are precise indicators of? @ToddMinehardt

Comment: Resistance to abrasion and deformation ([here](http://cameo.mfa.org/wiki/Hardness_(solids)#:~:text=A%20property%20of%20solids%20that,surface%20of%20a%20softer%20one.)). Google "Mohs scale" and go from there.

Comment: Wait. I was referring to hardness and softness in regard with the HSAB theory.

Comment: Ah. I go to hardness/softness (1) mechanical properties; then (2) in reference to calcium and magnesium concentration in water. Hence the confusion on my part -